# Edit image size after creation

Tags: javascript, image, titanium

```
var imageDisplayed = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image : somefile.png,
  height:'100',
  width:'100'
});
```

I have created the image in the above code. Now, how do I change the image size after that initial creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the property of your image view like this:

```
imageDisplayed.height = 120;
imageDisplayed.width = 120;
```